# Angular router "scrollPositionRestoration" not working well with router animations

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to design a site using Angular 8 with router animations. I have imported the `BrowserAnimationsModule` and I do see the animations work to some extent.

I'm also using the `scrollPositionRestoration` of Angular router to make sure that when users click on a link to see a new page, the top of the new page is shown instead of the previous scroll position.

However, when the router loads a new component into the view, it scrolls the entire window to the very top abruptly while applying the router animation. I tried disabling the `scrollPositionRestoration` property which indeed gets rid of the annoying scroll, however my new page is loaded at the previous scroll position instead of the top.

Here's a slackblitz that demonstrates my problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpadeg.

To recreate the problem, go to the "about" page, scroll down and then click on the "home" link and the abrupt scroll will show as the animation executes.

Comment: You need to provide the code for a minimal example in the question.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems that need to be overcome:

- both **previous** and **next** pages remain on the screen during animation, but might be of different heights
- scroll restoration  occurs immediately for the **next** page
- window height changes abruptly when the **previous** page is removed from the DOM (you'll notice the scroll bar height suddenly shrink/grow)

I've unfortunately gone through this before, and the solution involved a mix of disabling `scrollPositionRestoration`, listening to `NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, popstate`, applying scroll positions manually from a "cache" (a `Map` of pages and positions), and applying `position: fixed` to the **previous** page when the animation started (to keep it in position without being affected by the restoration of the **next** page position during the animation)

It wasn't worth the effort to be honest. I think you'd be better off applying a `fade in` type **Component** animation on the page content itself when the pages load. You could keep the `scrollPositionRestoration` enabled this way, and not have to deal with navigation events

In my opinion, **router animations should only be used when all pages are a fixed height**